# Unable to update connected users count (Node.js & Socket.io)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ecmascript-6

Testing out socket.io with vanilla node.js, I'm making a simple app to display online users count, using window title for simplicity. It worked fine on the server's console side, but it's not updating on the client's browser when I opened a new tab. What's the problem here? Here's the code:

```
var html = `
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('count updated', (data) => {
            //Worked on the current tab, didn't updating on the other tabs
            document.title = data + ' User(s) Online';
        });
    </script>
`;

var count = 0;    

var server = require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end(html);
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server).on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log(`${++count} User(s) Online`); //worked fine
    socket.emit('count updated', count); //worked once

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`${--count} User(s) Online`); //worked fine
        socket.emit('count updated', count); //didn't worked
    });
});

server.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't emit like that to a socket that just disconnected. You *can* however broadcast the count to all *connected* users instead. To do that, replace instances of `socket.emit('count updated', ..)` with:

```
io.sockets.emit('count updated', count);
```

or even simpler:

```
io.emit('count updated', count);
```

Comment: Thank you, problem solved. So what's the difference between socket.emit and io.emit that I missed? Could you explain me with the link?

Comment: `socket.emit()` emits an event *only* to that socket. `io.sockets.emit()`/`io.emit()` emits an event to *all connected sockets*.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

based on socket.io's example:
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js

you can use `socket.broadcast.emit('count updated', count)`